# Autoincrementar llave primaria al insertar un registro en mysql desde java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Estoy trabajando con java y mysql tengo el siguiente inconveniente con la base de datos tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE ARTICULO(

    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    COD_ARTICULO VARCHAR(40),
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(255),
    PRECIO DECIMAL,
    PROVEEDOR_ID_fk INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(PROVEEDOR_ID) REFERENCES PROVEEDORES(ID)
)
```

y esta otra:

```
CREATE TABLE PROVEEDORES(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ID_RUBRO INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(ID_RUBRO) REFERENCES TIPOS_PRODUCTOS(ID_TIPO),
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(80),
    CEDULA VARCHAR(50),
    TELEFONO VARCHAR(40),
    CORREO VARCHAR(70),
    DIRECCION TEXT
)
```

Como pueden ver hago referencia al `ID` de la tabla PROVEEDORES mediante una columna que es la clave foránea en mi tabla ARTICULO, hasta ahí bien, el problema es que como definí al `ID` de la tabla `PROVEEDORES` como llave foránea no puedo hacer un `autoincrement`  del ID de la tabla de proveedores ya que pues no se puede y al momento de realizar un `INSERT` desde **java** es imposible hacerlo ya que no le especifico que `ID` debe de tener ese campo y me devuelve el error de:

```
SQLException: Field 'ID' doesn't have a default value
```

Hay alguna manera de hacer que auto-incremente el ID de la tabla PROVEEDORES?. La solución "mas obvia" seria pues quitar que sea foráneo el campo `PROVEEDOR_ID_fk` y simplemente insertar los registros así. Pero seria buena idea esto? Hay alguna otra solucion?

Comment: No se si entiendo bien tu pregunta pero una clave fóranea es una referencia de una clave principal de otra tabla en tu base de datos, no entiendo porque querrías que se autoincrementara, sería más logico que al insertar la información donde va la clave foranea pongas la clave primaria del articulo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema fue desde el inicio de la creación de las tablas, no las marque como `AUTO_INCREMENT` y al intentar hacerlo ya con otras tablas enlazadas no me permitía. Solo tuve que crear las tablas con el campo ID como `AUTO_INCREMENT` y luego crear los `FOREIGN KEYS` de las otras tablas.

Answer (score 1):

Un campo auto incrementable no causa conflicto por ser llave foránea. Quizás tienes un error en el SQL del insert.

Cuando el campo que es auto incrementable está en la lista de campos a insertar, se debe pasar un valor `null` en la lista de valores.

Caso donde no se especifican las columnas, el valor del campo autoincrementable es `null`:

```
insert into PROVEEDORES 
values (null,'nombre','cedula','telefono','correo','direccion')
```

Caso donde el campo auto incrementable no está en la lista, no se necesita agregar valor `null`:

```
insert into PROVEEDORES
(nombre, cedula, telefono, correo, direccion)
values ('nombre','cedula','telefono','correo','direccion')
```